# psql: SELECT not showing results correctly in psql client

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, psql

OK, I have a Postgres table with a bunch of data. In particular, when I do a SELECT query with a condition on the `id`, it finds the result fine; but if I do it on the `person_id` column (which has a joint index between `person_id` and `course_id`), then it finds nothing. Specifically, it seems to fail to retrieve results based on the `person_id`; 10482 doesn't result in anything, but 10484 does.

What might be going on?

Transcript:

```
CS198=# select * from enrollments where id=19513;
select * from enrollments where id=19513;
  id   | person_id | course_id | position | seniority
-------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------
 19513 |     10482 |       177 | Student  |         0
(1 row)

Time: 0.345 ms
CS198=# select * from enrollments where id=19513 and person_id=10482;
select * from enrollments where id=19513 and person_id=10482;
  id   | person_id | course_id | position | seniority
-------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------
 19513 |     10482 |       177 | Student  |         0
(1 row)

Time: 0.370 ms
CS198=# select * from enrollments where person_id=10482;
select * from enrollments where person_id=10482;
Time: 0.369 ms
```

Note that in the last case... no results displayed. wtf?

Thanks in advance! I'm puzzled :P

EDIT: Strangely enough, as in the transcript above it isn't reporting that there is 0 rows of results; it just doesn't print anything at all. Normally when there are no results it would tell me that explicitly; maybe my Postgres configuration is messed up?

```
\timing on
\setenv LESS -imx4F
\x auto

\set HISTCONTROL ignorespace
\set HISTFILE ~/.psql_history- :DBNAME
\set HISTSIZE 20000

\pset null '[NULL]'
```

EDIT 2: Using Induction, a different SQL client instead of `psql`, it does show the missing results; so the real question is: what might be the problem with my `psql` configuration?

Comment: Looks like index trouble. Are you performing proper index maintenance? Try rebuilding the index on person_id.

Comment: Rebuilt the indexes on the table, and the specific joint index on `person_id` and `course_id`; no cigar :P This is a brand new database with freshly migrated data, so I haven't really performed any index maintenance at all.

Comment: That said see the EDIT: this may be a display issue as opposed to an actual data retrieval issue.

Comment: Multi-column indices can be tricky. Does the query work when you specify both `person_id` and `course_id` filter at the same time?

Comment: Yes, it does. hmmm, i probably should have an index on just `person_id` and `course_id` alone (thought rails would do that but apparently not)—but ignoring that, I'm still curious what might be going on.

Comment: Does this also happen with other SQL clients?

Comment: Just tried it in Induction, it does show the results. I do think it's a display issue then

Comment: Try starting `psql` with the `-X` option to disable the use of `.psqlrc` then you would see if it's your local configuration or something different